# Isn't this a pointer functionality in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, pointers

In one of my projects, I had to copy values of one array to another.

When i tried doing it this way :

```
 var Arr1 = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
 var Arr2 = Arr1;        // will this create a pointer ??
```

Is it creating a pointer ?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/janakshah89/KuAgN/) : I mean after the loop,if i try to access Arr1, it returns empty.

```
for(var i=0;i<Counter;i++)
{
    $('#testDiv').append(Arr2.pop() + " ");
}       
    alert("The element in other array : "  + Arr1);
```

Is there anything like pointer in javascript ?

Comment: Both Arr1 and Arr2 points to the same array

Comment: if i want to retain value of Arr1 and make changes to just Arr2 how do i do it ?

Comment: @janakshah http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `Arr1.slice(0)`:

http://jsfiddle.net/L23nR/

Answer (score 3):

Assignments in JavaScript indeed create a **reference** to the right hand side.

A **pointer** is a type of reference, but also has the following two properties:

- It refers to a specific memory address.
- One can add or subtract from it to get other memory addresses that are equally valid.

Both of these conditions are not met in plain JavaScript, although an implementation could surely provide a native function for these.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var Arr2 = Arr1.slice(0);
```

From here: http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
var Arr2 = Arr1;
```

with

```
var Arr2 = Arr1.slice();
```

Check here : http://jsfiddle.net/dk7E6/

```
var Arr2 = Arr1;
```

This creates an array reference to `Arr1`  so if you modify `Arr2` then `Arr1` will be changed automatically .. So to get a copy of an array use `array.slice()`

Answer (score 1):

In essence, yes. Values in JavaScript are references, so the variables `Arr1` and `Arr2` both refer to the same array instance in memory. All values are copied by reference upon assignment, so everything is a 'pointer' in JavaScript.